# Numpy: shuffle subset of elements

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

I have a 2-D numpy-array, interpreting it as a grid, and want to permute a subset of the elements.
More precisely, an edge shall be mapped to an edge and a corner mapped to a corner.

- `np.random.shuffle` does the job, when any permutation of elements is fine.

I can access the corners by:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]]
```

However, when I call

```
np.random.shuffle(a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]])
```

the array is not changed. Reading https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html, I found out that the above used **Advanced Slicing**, which returns a copy, instead of a view.
But this copy is shuffled in-place, so there is no result to be assigned to the original array.

So the questions is, how can I permute the elements of the chosen indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) to get a shuffled copy of an input sequence, and then assign this using indexing:

```
In [19]: a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

In [20]: a
Out[20]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [21]: a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]] = np.random.permutation(a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]])

In [22]: a
Out[22]:
array([[12,  1,  2, 15],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0, 13, 14,  3]])
```

Also, you *can* get a **view** of the 4 corners of your array using `a[::a.shape[0]-1, ::a.shape[1]-1]`

However, since the result from that is a two-dimensional numpy array, shuffling will only shuffle along the first axis.

Comment: This problem of shuffling only 1 dimension also happened, when I tried to use `shuffle` on the central part, but also `permutation` has this issue for `np.random.permutation(a[1:-1,1:-1])`, so I will try the advanced indexing there as well.

Comment: Numpy indexing takes a while to get the hang of, but very, very powerful.  Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is that np.random.shuffle does change the array in-place and never returns a value, ordering the entries randomly. Your code changes the new and temporary array containing the corners, which is changed, but you have no reference to it, so you see no changes. Check out:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> np.random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3]])
>>> np.random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]]
array([ 0,  3,  8, 11])
>>> np.random.shuffle(a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]])
>>> b = a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]]
>>> np.random.shuffle(b)
>>> b
array([ 0, 11,  8,  3])
>>>
```

Now you just have to reassign the corners using b. And take care, the corners in my example were taken from the already shuffled array a.

Comment: Your code does solve the problem. However, it looks like this is just the more explicit/verbose version of `np.random.permutation` (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: According to the  the documentation there are more subtle differences:

Comment: Permutation copies the array and subarrays before performing the permutation before the shuffling. And there is also the convenience method `np.random.permutation(n)` to generate a random array with numbers from 0 to n. See [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html] and the previous topic in the documentation. In your case this does not matter as you permutate only the selected corners and reassign them.